# Replace WCF default JSON serialization

Tags: wcf, json, serialization

Is it possible to replace the default JSON serialization of WCF (I'm currently testing with the `webHttp` behaviour), and passing `application/json` as the MIME type. In particular, I don't like that by default every property is a key/value pair like:

```
{"Key":"PropertyName", "Value":"PropertyValue"}
```

I'm using the service only for JSON-enabled endpoints (requesting data with jQuery + WCF).

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372076/post-json-dictionary-without-key-value-text/38440427#38440427

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a message formatter to change the serializer used to deal with JSON. The post at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/carlosfigueira/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters shows an example on how to change the default serializer (DataContractJsonSerializer) to another one (JSON.NET).

Comment: Thanks Carlos. It wasn't easy but I finally got it working.(I forgot the contentTypeMapper :)) )

Comment: Brilliant blog post. Making it super easy to support both json and XML formatting even using NewtonSoft's variation. :)

Answer (score -1):

Consider creating classes corresponding to your JSON object structure. In that case you don't have to use `Dictionary<>` like:

```
[DataContract]
public class Customer
{
    [DataMember(Name="name")]
    public string Name{get;set;}

    [DataMember(Name="id")]
    public int ID{get;set;}
}
```

This get serialized as:

```
{"name": "name-value", "id": "id-value"}
```

Of course, this is just an alternative to what you already have and may not be applicable.