# XMLserialize object of list and string

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, serialization, xml-serialization

So i need to xml serialize a generic list of objects where the object consists of another list and a string.

This is what i get now

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<ArrayOfRecept xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


-<Recept>
<Namn>Nomnom</Namn>    
</Recept>

-<Recept>    
<Namn>Ännu mer nomnom</Namn>    
</Recept>

</ArrayOfRecept>
```

Here only the string value is serialized and not my List

This is my object that i want to serialize

```
public class Recept
    {

        private ListHanterare<string> ingredienser;
        private string namn;

        public Recept()
        {
            ingredienser = new ListHanterare<string>();
        }
        public ListHanterare<string> Ingredienser
        {
            get { return ingredienser; }

        }

        public string Namn
        {
            get { return namn; }
            set { namn = value; }
        }

    }
```

So I will have a list of Recept that i want to xml serialize and I want the xml to show both "Namn" and the "Ingredienser"-list.

This is my serializer

```
 class XMLSerial
    {
        public static bool Serialize<T>(T obj, string filePath)
        {
            bool bok = true;

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath);
            try
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
            }
            catch
            {
                bok = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (writer != null)

                    writer.Close();
            }

            return bok;
        }

    }
```

This is inside the ListHanterare class where I pass the object to the serializer

```
public bool XMLSerialize(string filePath){
            return XMLSerial.Serialize<List<T>>(lista, filePath);
```

EDIT:
So by adding a setter to ingredienser I now get this

```
-<Recept>
<Ingredienser/>
<Namn>rec</Namn>
</Recept>
```

But ingredienser is still empty 
My ListHanterare class is a basic generic List class

```
public class ListHanterare<T> : IListHanterare<T>
    {

        private List<T> lista; // This is the list
        private int count;

        public ListHanterare()
        {
            lista = new List<T>();

        }
```

So i need to serialize a ListHanterare list of Recept objects where the Recept object consists of a string and another ListHanterare list of strings, the string is serialized correctly but not the list of strings.

Comment: Add XML Element to your Recept Class so your Serializer would know what to Deserialize. Also, you're not Deserializing your Elements you're just streaming and returning the value as TRUE - bool. You're not returning anything its either false or true.

Comment: I have a [Serializable] above my class declaration

Comment: `[Serializable]` is for binary formatting not `XmlSerializer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `XmlSerializer` to serialize or deserialize the property `Ingredienser` of your `Recept` class, it must have a public setter as well as a public getter:

```
    public ListHanterare<string> Ingredienser
    {
        get { return ingredienser; }
        set { ingredienser = value; } 
    }
```

If you don't do this, `XmlSerializer` will ignore the property.

You might still have problems with the class `ListHanterare`, but it's not shown in your question.

[`DataContractSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not have this requirement.  However, to serialize and deserialize your classes with `DataContractSerializer` and include private fields or properties, you would need to fully annotate them with [data contract attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Private field and properties marked with [`[DataMember]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) get serialized despite being private.  Data contract serialization is [opt-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964866/datacontractserializer-is-an-opt-in-serializer-how-to-make-it-opt-out), however, so to use this feature your classes would need to be fully attributed.

**Update**

You don't show the complete code of your `ListHanterare<string>` class.  In order for `XmlSerializer` to serialize and deserialize it successfully, it must either:

1. Make all its contents available in publicly settable and gettable properties, or
2. Implement `ICollection<T>` (or even `IList<T>`) as described here: [XmlSerializer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

For method #1, you could modify your class as follows:

```
public class ListHanterare<T> 
{
    private List<T> lista; // This is the list
    private int count;

    public ListHanterare()
    {
        lista = new List<T>();
    }

    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public T[] SerializableList
    {
        get
        {
            return (lista == null ? new T [0] : lista.ToArray());
        }
        set
        {
            if (lista == null)
                lista = new List<T>();
            lista.Clear();
            lista.AddRange(value ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>());
            count = lista.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

You will now see the items serialized your XML.

Comment: By giving it a setter gave me this result <Recept>

<Ingredienser/>

<Namn>hehe</Namn>

</Recept>   Would using DataContractSerializer fix this ?

Comment: @user3621898 - what does your `ListHanterare` class look like?  If its contents are not being serialized, the problem may be there.

Comment: @user3621898 - Probably your `ListHanterare` does not have the publicly settable properties required by `XmlSerializer` -- but I can't say for sure.  Can you show the complete code of `ListHanterare`?

Comment: Your code worked thank you, could you explain how the get line works there? also the double questionmark line

Comment: The result i get looks sthg like this <Ingredienser><SerializableList xmlns....><a:string>ingrediens</a:string></serializablelist></ingredienser> is there anyway to make it without the serializable tag ?

Comment: @user3621898 - the `[XmlElement("Item")]` should have eliminated the `SerializableList` element from the XML.  Did you remove it?  The `??` line is to avoid throwing an exception on a `null` input.