# Json write can not be serialized

Tags: c#, json, datacontractjsonserializer

**Process:**

1. Create the `Player` class.
2. Create the player `List<Player>()`.
3. Add players to the list.
4. Write a `json` serial file.

   When I click on `writeJson` button I receive the error:

   ```
   "Type `'EditPlayers.Player'` cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the 
   `DataContractAttribute` attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized 
   with the `DataMemberAttribute` attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking 
   it with the `CollectionDataContractAttribute`.See the Microsoft .NET Framework 
   documentation for other supported types."
   ```

**Question:**

How to mark `List<Player>()` with the `CollectionDataContractAttribute`.

```
class Player
{
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    public int Gender { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public int Tee { get; set; }
    public int Team { get; set; }
    public int Flight { get; set; }
    public int Ohc { get; set; }
    public decimal HcIx { get; set; }
}

private async void writeJason_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await writeJsonAsync();
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}

private async void readJason_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await deserializerJsonAsync();
}

private List<Player> buildObjectGraph()
{
    var players = new List<Player>();
    players.Add(new Player() {MemberId=1, Gender=0, LName="Player", FName="New", Tee=1, Team=0, Flight=0, Ohc=0, HcIx=0M});
    players.Add(new Player() {MemberId=2, Gender=0, LName="Draw", FName="Blind", Tee=1, Team=0, Flight=0, Ohc=0, HcIx=0M});
    players.Add(new Player() {MemberId=3, Gender=0, LName="Moles", FName="Mike", Tee=1, Team=4, Flight=1, Ohc=2, HcIx=2.0M});
    players.Add(new Player() {MemberId=4, Gender=0, LName="Broemeling", FName="Donald", Tee=1, Team=4, Flight=2, Ohc=10, HcIx=10.0M});
    players.Add(new Player() {MemberId=5, Gender=0, LName="Nelson", FName="David", Tee=1, Team=4, Flight=3, Ohc=11, HcIx=11.7M});
    players.Add(new Player() {MemberId=6, Gender=0, LName="Moles", FName="David", Tee=1, Team=4, Flight=4, Ohc=20, HcIx=20.0M});
    players.Add(new Player() {MemberId=7, Gender=0, LName="Player", FName="A", Tee=1, Team=1, Flight=1, Ohc=0, HcIx=0M});
    players.Add(new Player() {MemberId=8, Gender=0, LName="Player", FName="B", Tee=1, Team=1, Flight=2, Ohc=0, HcIx=0M});
    players.Add(new Player() {MemberId=9, Gender=0, LName="Player", FName="C", Tee=1, Team=1, Flight=3, Ohc=0, HcIx=0M});
    players.Add(new Player() {MemberId=10,Gender=0, LName="Player", FName="D", Tee=1, Team=1, Flight=4, Ohc=0, HcIx=0M});
    return players;
}
private async Task writeJsonAsync()
{
    var allPlayers = buildObjectGraph();
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Player>));
    //using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(
    //    JSONFILENAME,
    //    CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
    using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(
    JSONFILENAME, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
    {
        serializer.WriteObject(stream, allPlayers);
    }
    resultTextBlock.Text = "Write succeeded";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mark `List<Player>()` with `CollectionDataContractAttribute`.  Instead, you need to make the `Player` class be serializable by `DataContractJsonSerializer`, as described by the documentation: [Types Supported by the Data Contract Serializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The easiest solution is to mark `Player` with the [`Serializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute:

```
[Serializable]
class Player
{
    // Remainder unchanged
}
```

Alternatively you could annotate it with [`[DataContract]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`[DataMember]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attributes:

```
[DataContract]
class Player
{
    [DataMember]
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Gender { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string FName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Tee { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Team { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Flight { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Ohc { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public decimal HcIx { get; set; }
}
```

Either way, your `List<Player>` will be serializable by `DataContractJsonSerializer`.

Note that data contract serialization is [opt-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964866/datacontractserializer-is-an-opt-in-serializer-how-to-make-it-opt-out) so you must mark every property or field to be serialized with `[DataMember]`.

Comment: @DaveNelson - You're welcome.  If the question is answered, please do [mark it as such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow).