# What is opt in serializer

Tags: wcf, serialization

I am learning wcf, and I am seeing this opt in and opt out serialization. I am still scratching my head. I have already seen [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19964866/1977871). But it didn't help. Can someone explain me succinctly what it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually its so simple:
Opt-In approach says properties that are considered to be part of DataContract must be explicitly marked othewise will be ignore, while Opt-Out means all of the properties will be assumed to be part of the DataContract unless marked explicitly.

```
namespace MySchoolService

    {
                    [DataContract]
                    public class Student
                   {
                           [DataMember]
                           public string StudentNumber;
                           [DataMember]
                           public string FirstName;
                           [DataMember]
                           public string LastName;                     

                          public string MarksObtained;
                   }
                  [ServiceContract]
                   public interface IStudentService
                   {
                              //Service Code Here.
                   }
    }
```

In above code `StudentNumber`, `FirstName`, `LastName` properties of `Student` class are explicitly marked with `DataMember` attribute as oppose to `MarksObtained`, so `MarksObtained` will be ignored.
Below code represents an example of Opt-Out approach.

```
namespace MySchoolService
{
                [Serializable()]
                public class Student
               {
                       public string StudentNumber;
                       public string FirstName;
                       public string LastName;                     
                      [NonSerialized()]
                      public string marksObtained;
               }               
               [ServiceContract]
               public interface IStudentService
               {
                          //Service Code Here.
               }
}
```

In above example, we explicitly marked `MarksObtained` property as `[NonSerialized()]` attribute, so it will be ignored except the others.
hope could help you.