# DataMember Name property not working in entity framework

Tags: c#, serialization, entity-framework-6

I have Dto like this:

```
public class OptimizationNodeDto : IModelWithId
    {        
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "parentId")]
        public int? ParentOptimizationNodeId { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "opened")]
        public bool IsOpened { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "selected")]
        public SelectedStates SelectedState { get; set; }

        public List<OptimizationNodeDto> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

I want that when I send this object with any API it should give property name in JSON as like mentioned in DataMember but it's not happening. For ex.ParentOptimizationNodeId  should be as parentId in JSON result.
Here I am sending the Dto:

```
 [Route("{roleId}/Optimizations")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult GetOptimizationList([FromUri]int roleId, [FromBody] FilterDto filter)
        {
            try
            {
                var groupManBo = _serviceLocator.Resolve<IRoleManagerBo>();
                return Ok(groupManBo.GetOptimization(roleId, this.ViewboxUser, filter));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return this.HandleError(ex);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What Json serialiser are you using?

Comment: I am new for Json serialiser. Will you please suggest steps to do it.

Comment: Ummmm, well where is the code where you send this DTO?

Comment: I update my question.

Comment: Okay so I think `[DataMember]` isn't the correct attribute to rename your JSON keys, I think `[JsonProperty(PropertyName="")]` is the one you want.

Comment: Are you also marking your type with [`[DataContract]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx)?  From your question it looks as though you may not be, but perhaps you omitted the attribute when you pasted your code into the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`DataMemberAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx) is ignored by both [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DataContractAndDataMember.htm) and [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) unless [`[DataContract]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx) is also applied to the type itself.  From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx#Anchor_6):

> Apply the DataMemberAttribute attribute **in conjunction with the DataContractAttribute** to identify members of a type that are part of a data contract.

Thus your DTO must look like:

```
[DataContract]
public class OptimizationNodeDto : IModelWithId
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "parentId")]
    public int? ParentOptimizationNodeId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "opened")]
    public bool IsOpened { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "selected")]
    public SelectedStates SelectedState { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<OptimizationNodeDto> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Note that data contract serialization is [opt-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964866/datacontractserializer-is-an-opt-in-serializer-how-to-make-it-opt-out) so you now must also mark `Id` and `Children` with `[DataMember]`.

Answer (score 2):

See [.NET NewtonSoft JSON deserialize map to a different property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915503/net-newtonsoft-json-deserialize-map-to-a-different-property-name)

```
[JsonProperty("new name")]
public string SomeColumn { get; set; }
```

However, this would assume you are using Newtonsoft as the JSON serializer.  If you replaced it with a different one, you'd have to use the attributes specific to that serializer.