# Deserialize JSON object which has property name as number into a object in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, wcf, object, properties

I have below JSON object

```
myvalues : {
     0 : "value0",
     1 : "value1",
     2 : "value2",
     3 : "value3"
}
```

I want to bind this JSON object into a vb.net class object as an input to a WCF `OperationContract` method - but I can't define the numeric property names as numbers.  I am getting the error message:

> Identifier expected on property names because property name cannot be a number

Using the following:

```
Public class myvalues_class

    public property 0 as string
    public property 1 as string
    public property 2 as string
    public property 3 as string

end class
```

how can I convert this JSON object to a vb.net object class?

Comment: Looks more like a dictionary than a list of properties. If you really want properties, you can take a look at DataContract

Comment: You can deserialize `myvalues` into a `Dictionary(Of Integer, String)` or add `<JsonProperty("N")>` attributes to the properties in `myvalues_class` as in [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536564/3744182).  That question is for c# but the same answers apply.  Agree it's a duplicate?

Comment: @dbc thanks for answer.  I tried to add `<JsonProperty("0")> _`  above of property and error message gone. But cannot deserialize JSON property 0 into VB.NET class property 0. Yes unfortunatelly a duplicate. Sorry

Comment: Glad to help & no need to apologize - your question is clear and has no vb.net duplicate.  *But cannot deserialize JSON property 0 into VB.NET class property 0.* - so do you still have a problem?

Comment: @dbc yes unfortunately i still have a problem. Cannot deserialize json into a vb.net object. I also tried `<JsonProperty(PropertyName:="0")> _` but doesn't changed anything. cannot deserialize json object. Canyou check [link]https://pastebin.com/RDYuSs2W please

Comment: @dbc and the other members being converted without any problem except "values" member. firstName, lastname has no problem. Problem is only on "values", always converting r,g,b,a values as 0 (because defined as byte)

Comment: Seems like it works perfectly, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/fvR9ED

Comment: Or maybe you're not using [tag:json.net]?  What serializer are you using?  Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: @dbc thanks for answer.This is WCF service which has getting JSON object from client as POST. I using Javascript to post JSON object into WCF service. Please check this Link [link]https://pastebin.com/QDjkBiVm so i don need to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject ` code for convert. because WCF service doing this.

Comment: Well WCF uses `DataContractJsonSerializer` so you need to use data contract attributes....

Comment: @dbc oh man :) thanks It's worked like charm. I tried `<DataMember> _` before you say, but i had never thought about using `<DataMember(Name:="0")> _` before. Really thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[wcf](/questions/tagged/wcf) uses [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer), so you will need to annotate your `Values` type with [data contract attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-data-contracts) that map some validly-named vb.net properties to the JSON numeric property names, e.g. like so:

```
<System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract> _
Public Class Values
    <DataMember(Name:="0")> _
    Public Property r As Integer

    <DataMember(Name:="1")> _
    Public Property g As Integer

     <DataMember(Name:="2")> _
    Public Property b As Integer

    <DataMember(Name:="3")> _
    Public Property a As Integer
End Class
```

Note that the data contract serializers are [opt-in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19964866) so you will have to mark *all* properties to be serialized with [`DataMemberAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute).